# Eliminating undesired characters from every string in an Array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift3, character

I have an array called coordinateArray that is holding this data:

```
["(19.452187074041884", " -99.1457748413086)", "(19.443769985032485", " -99.14852142333984)", "(19.443446242121073", " -99.13787841796875)", "(19.450244707639662", " -99.13822174072266)"]
["(19.407780723677718", " -99.18417591514299)", "(19.400373302640162", " -99.18473381461808)", "(19.400049473260434", " -99.18039936485002)", "(19.405433052977592", " -99.17838234367082)"]
["(19.4022042123319", " -99.1457748413086)", "(19.401070819438004", " -99.16139602661133)", "(19.39184146912981", " -99.16268348693848)", "(19.389736456288546", " -99.14706230163574)"]
["(19.42114689571205", " -99.17375564575195)", "(19.425598915444077", " -99.15392875671387)", "(19.414913863184566", " -99.15470123291016)", "(19.41264724664359", " -99.16594505310059)", "(19.412890099927345", " -99.16766166687012)"]
```

I need to remove the parenthesis from each coordinate

How can I do this in Swift 3.0?

I tried to do this

```
let coordinateArray = coor.components(separatedBy: ",")                    
                    var coordinateArrayF = [String]()
                    for coordinate in coordinateArray {
                        let coordinatevar = coordinate.replacingOccurrences(of: "()", with: "")
                        coordinateArrayF.append(coordinatevar)
                    }
```

But it isn't working what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Better fix the code that *generates* the array, and make it an array of tuples or  CLLocationCoordinate2D  or something like that.

Comment: That was what I was trying to do since the beginning but I don't know how!

I'm generating the array from a huge string of coordinates using components(separatedBy: ",") what would I need to do to make an array of CLLocationCoordinate2D? Thanks

what I'm receiving

Answer (score 1):

Functional programming is your friend!

```
var data = ["(19.452187074041884", " -99.1457748413086)", "(19.443769985032485", " -99.14852142333984)", "(19.443446242121073", " -99.13787841796875)", "(19.450244707639662", " -99.13822174072266)"]

let cleanData = data.map { 
     item in item.replacingOccurrences(of: "(", with: "")
}
```

Comment: thanks I did something very similar but with a for loop, it's really nice to understand how to do it using functional programming. what was preventing it from working is that you need to create a regular ocurrence in the replacingOcurrences(of: "" with: "") method. I'll post the answer on how I solved it.